# Alpha Software v 9

Tags: database, alpha

I am not a 'programmer' but want to develop a database application using Alpha Software Platinum v 9.  The app would allow users to list classified ads via a web site and browse for items being sold etc.  Does anyone have experience with Alpha software and is it really as easy they state on their site?  Again, I am not a programmer but the info says you don't have to be to use their software. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have not used the software, but my advice would be:

**Do not attempt what you say you are going to without significant programming experience**.

Sooner or later you will need to troubleshoot your application (if you get that far), and you will need programming skills.